# Does the redshift have anything to do with Compton scattering?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, redshift

The more I think about it the more I can't help but feel that the redshift must be caused by a form of Compton scattering and the interaction between particles of light and electrons. Is this viewpoint correct?

Comment: The red shift of what, exactly?

Comment: Light. Is there the red shift of anything else?

Comment: I know that red shift deals with light. I mean what light? What system are you referring to? You are talking about light interacting with electrons, but there are many scenarios where this can happen.

Comment: What about red-shifted galaxies?

Comment: Why do you think that the usual explanation of red shift is incorrect in the red shift of  galaxies. It might help to expand on your thoughts instead of just saying you have thought about it. You say that your idea *must* be true, but you don't say why. This question will be hard to answer without knowing more about what you are thinking

Comment: Compton scattering by what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could the redshift be possible without a form of Compton scattering?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451317/could-the-redshift-be-possible-without-a-form-of-compton-scattering) by the very same OP.

Answer (score 1):

No, that viewpoint is incorrect. Light redshifts even in the absence of electrons. Redshift has nothing to do with any kind of scattering.

Every time an ambulance goes by, you hear its siren shift to a lower frequency. This is a “redshift” for sound.

Whether for sound or for light, redshift is typically a simple kinematical effect where the wavelength of a wave gets stretched out by the motion of the source away from the receiver. There is also gravitational redshift, which is related to time dilation. But scattering is not involved.

Comment: The Doppler shift of an ambulances siren is caused by the fact that the source of the sound waves is moving away and hence the waves have to travel through an increasingly large amount of air. This idea of electrons in space would be analogous to that.

Comment: @SamCottle No, electrons in space would not be analogous to that.

Comment: If a galaxy/siren is to exhibit a Doppler shift it would need to be travelling through a medium, either air molecules or a sea of particles in space. It's analogous to it in that it's a medium through which waves propagate.

Comment: No. The light from a galaxy can travel just fine through vacuum. Intergalactic space is not filled with electrons. The idea that you need a medium for light to propagate in died more than 100 years ago.

Comment: It's similar to the aether yes, but that idea also definitely hasn't died; you should look into Loop Quantum Gravity. Also look into the idea of a Dirac Sea, it's more in line with this way of thinking.

Comment: Have fun with your ideas, Sam, but don’t expect Physics SE to embrace them. No one has supported your idea that redshift is related to Compton scattering. Our discussion has now reached the limit where we are being asked to stop, so I will do so.

Comment: I can't see why you're being asked to stop. As far as I'm aware this website isn't affiliated with any institution nor does it represent the opinions of the research community As for embracing an attitude of free inquiry, in science of all things, I have to say that I'm actually appalled by the attitudes of some users on here.

Comment: This is not a site for free inquiry. If it were, it would be inundated with cranks and the relatively few actual phyicists would quickly leave. We have better things to do than waste our time with people who are not interested in learning, The site is quite clear that it is a site for discussing mainstream physics only. Questions get closed all the time for violating this policy. If you find that appalling, you should find a more compatible site.

Comment: @SamCottle [Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: … **Non-mainstream physics, including pitches for personal theories** We deal with mainstream physics here. Anything that couldn't be published in a reputable journal is not appropriate on this site. …](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)